# Making a 2D grid of Sprites

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, sprite

I just finished my first coding class (IB Computer Science, if that helps), and I decided I wanted to make my first game.

The game world I have currently is a top-down view of the terrain. Each part of the terrain is made up of squares (it is very similar to the way Dwarf Fortress looks). I have been able to get it to output to console, using characters for stand-in graphics, but my course covered very little on graphics work.

What is the best way to create a grid of sprites or colored squares inside a JPanel? I have been able to display BufferedImages before, but have not been able to align multiple BufferedImages to get a grid.

As of now, I have an '2D' ArrayList, just an ArrayList of an ArrayList, making up my game world. It all works great when I use a double for loop and System.out.print("");

Comment: *"What is the best way to create a grid of sprites or colored squares inside a JPanel?"*  `GridLayout`

Comment: Why are you mentioning that this is your first game? The personal background is unnecessary to our answer, so it shouldn't be in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the oracle documentaion for [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  The one you are looking for is Grid Layout.

If you feel fancy, you can upgrade to JavaFX, and use a [Grid Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) instead.

Comment: *"If you feel fancy, you can upgrade to JavaFX,.."*  The Swing tag kind of indicates 'no' & `GirdLayout` is perfectly up to the task.

Comment: Just providing options :)